# discretize the bounding box to 40x40 grid

Tags: java, algorithm, geolocation, latitude-longitude, bounding-box

I have two positions (lat, long): A and B, which are given as a bounding box.
A : (41, 7)
B : (43, 8)

I need to make a 40x40 grid to discretize the bounding box.

```
41,8. . . . 43,8
.           .
.           .
.           .
.           .
41,7. . . . 43,7
```

One of the points that I get is (41.005, 7.001).

How can I make this grid in Java to get 1600 points of out of this bounding box?

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Make sure a.x<b.x & a.y <b.y
    Point a = new Point(41,7);
    Point b = new Point(43,8);
    final int gridsize = 40;        

    ArrayList<Point> grid = new ArrayList<Point>(gridsize*gridsize);
    for (double i = a.getX(); i <= b.getX(); i += b.getX() - a.getX() / (double)(gridsize-1))
        for (double j = a.getY(); j <= b.getY(); j +=  b.getY()- a.getY() / (double)(gridsize-1))
            grid.add(new Point(i, j));
```

I'm not perfectly sure I understood your question, but this code will create an array list containing a grid of 1600 (gridsize^2) points in a 40*40 grid in the wanted perimetter.

The Point object used here is a couble of doubles called x and y, you will need to create this object.